# Record commands only to file

Tags: shell-script

How can I record commands only to a file?

I imagine something like the `script` command, but not recording prompts or the OS response, just the entered commands followed by a line feed.

I want to record a series of frequently used commands so I can put them in a shell script.

Answer (score 3):

look for "history" related commands in the man page for your shell. most shells can write this to a file or set up a repeating prompt command to do it.